# GDirections Route on Map View Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview

I am using `AFNetworking`, and I am following a tutorial about drawing routes on the iphone screen by getting directions from google directions. I am using `JSON`, and `AFNetworking`. I copied the code in from the tutorial you can find here: [Tutorial](http://iosguy.com/tag/directions-api/)

If you also choose to copy and test this code, just a note: You need the `AFNetworking` from this github page: [AFNetworking Download](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/)

You also have to define the variable `_path` as an `NSMutableArray` in the .h yourself or you will get errors as they have not defined it but referenced it.

Here is the  code:

```
        AFHTTPClient *_httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/"]];

    [_httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass: [AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [parameters setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"origin"];

    [parameters setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", location2.coordinate.latitude, location2.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"destination"];

    [parameters setObject:@"true" forKey:@"sensor"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [_httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path: @"maps/api/directions/json" parameters:parameters];

    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) { 
        NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            [self parseResponse:response];

        } else {

        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { }]; 

    [_httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

**So heres my problem**

Thank you to those who helped. I have tested out the code with no errors, but now found that while trying to make a route. It crashes here:

```
- (void)parseResponse:(NSDictionary *)response {

    NSArray *routes = [response objectForKey:@"routes"]; // CRASH HERE

    NSDictionary *routePath = [routes lastObject];

    if (routePath) {

        NSString *overviewPolyline = [[routePath objectForKey: @"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];

        _path = [self decodePolyLine:overviewPolyline];

        NSInteger numberOfSteps = _path.count;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
            CLLocation *location = [_path objectAtIndex:index];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

            coordinates[index] = coordinate;
        }

        MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:polyLine];

        }

    }
```

With the error description:

> -[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2004bb80

Can you guys help? Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't have the latest AFNetworking code. You should *not* modify the code from AFNetworking!

Comment: Oh sorry ok, let me download the newest code.

Comment: try to create a `AFJSONRequestOperation` explicitly instead of using `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest`

Comment: @phix23 How would I do that? Im sorry Im quite new to AFNetworking, could you update your answer with a demonstration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after playing a bit I figured it out. The `route` would only be an `NSDictionary` if `JSONKit` was included. Some relation with `AFNetworking` and `JSONKit` here. So, I already had the `JSONKit` files from before, because I knew about this. But `AFHTTPClient` was not accepting it, so I had to put the line:

```
        [_httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

Answer (score 2):

> Let me also say that the AFHTTPClient previously did not have this
>   HTTPOperationWithRequest class method as shown, but I had to copy and
>   paste it in from AFHTTPRequestOperation.

I cloned `AFNetworking` from your github link and found this in `AFHTTPClient.h` file:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                                                    success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

I wonder why you are getting errors instead of "method not found" warning. `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` is instance method, not class method:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [_httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // do something
        ;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        ;
    }];
```

By the way, tutorial you linked has it correctly.

Comment: Yes, the AFNetworking code I had was dragged in from my old project which means it was old code. I am going to redownload the AFNetworking project. I made it the class method, because when I tried to make it an instance method i was getting errors

Comment: can you test this code out for me? Ive updated my question about a crash for the routes

Comment: how can i create a AFJSONRequestOperation explicitly instead of using HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest